# How do i fetch sqlite data in autocompletetextview?

Tags: android, sqlite

I need to fetch data from database and set in autocompletetextview but i got error which i  try to fix but unable to fix it. and also i am trying to fetch all data by using Id that will be selected through auto complete text view when the user enters itemcode.

In Fragment

```
    AutoCompleteTextView ItemCode; 

    ItemCode=(AutoCompleteTextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.purchase_xml_item_code);


helper=new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
    LoadeAutoCompleteItemCode();
```

In LoadeAutoCompleteItemCode

```
private void LoadeAutoCompleteItemCode() {

        final String[] autoCompleteItemeCode = helper.AutoCompleteItemeCode();
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, autoCompleteItemeCode);
        ItemCode.setAdapter(adapter);
        ItemCode.setThreshold(1);
        ItemCode.dismissDropDown();
        ItemCode.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), (CharSequence) parent.getItemAtPosition(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
```

in my Database Helper AutoCompleteItemCode

```
 public String[] AutoCompleteItemeCode() {
        try {
            String arrData[] = null;
            SQLiteDatabase db;
            db = this.getReadableDatabase();

            String strSQL = "SELECT C.ID FROM " + Verbs.ITable_Name+" AS C ";
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(strSQL, null);
            if (cursor != null) {

                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    arrData = new String[cursor.getCount()];
                    int i = 0;
                    do {
                        arrData[i] = cursor.getString(0);
                        i++;
                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }
            }
            cursor.close();
            return arrData;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

In My XML File

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
                        android:id="@+id/purchase_xml_item_code"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView_itemcode"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView_itemcode"
                        android:background="@color/editTextBG"
                        android:hint="@string/purchase_item_code"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                        android:textSize="25sp" />
```

My Error Logs

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  java.lang.NullPointerException
                      at com.example.admin6.finaldemo.Fragment.Transaction.Purchase.LoadeAutoCompleteItemCode(Purchase.java:189)
                      at com.example.admin6.finaldemo.Fragment.Transaction.Purchase.onCreateView(Purchase.java:72)
                      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2439)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
                      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:733)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 32197 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

As Error logs Purchase.java:189 on this line indicates here

```
final String[] autoCompleteItemeCode = helper.AutoCompleteItemeCode();
```

Comment: What is at Purchase.java:72?

Comment: LoadeAutoCompleteItemCode(); at Purchase.java.72

Comment: in AutoCompleteItemeCode in catch block add  e.printStackTrace();

Comment: added it but nothing change logs are same

Comment: Use arraylist instead of string[], when you query will return 0 results it will send null string [] which will throw Null Pointer

Comment: Is "helper" `null`? Because that is the only thing that can throw a `NullPointerException` in `final String[] autoCompleteItemeCode = helper.AutoCompleteItemeCode();` that is not bubbling up from the `AutoCompleteItemeCode` function itself. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: @LWChris  helper is not null  helper  helper=new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());

Comment: @ShubhamHingne Where is that `helper=new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());` line in your code? It's not in the excerpts you posted, so maybe it would only be reached after the call of `LoadeAutoCompleteItemCode()`? Try inserting this as first line of `LoadeAutoCompleteItemCode`: `if (helper == null) { Log.e("Helper is null"); }`. If you see that output on the console, you know helper is not initialized yet.

Comment: @LWChris the helper=new DatabaseHelper(getActivity()); is insid the onCreateView  and the body of LoadeAutoCompleteItemCode() outside of onCreateView which i called .inside of onCreateView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use arraylist instead of string[], when you query will return 0 results it will send null string [] which will throw Null Pointer.

```
public ArrayList<String> AutoCompleteItemeCode() {
        ArrayList<String> arrData=new ArrayList();
        try {


            SQLiteDatabase db;
            db = this.getReadableDatabase();

            String strSQL = "SELECT C.ID FROM " + Verbs.ITable_Name+" AS C ";
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(strSQL, null);
            if (cursor != null) {

                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {


                    do {
                        arrData.add( cursor.getString(0));

                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }
            }
            cursor.close();
            return arrData;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please try this?

Comment: in catch block instead of null write arrdata

Comment: tried but same result. i remember that ID that saved in database is Integer and i used cursor.getString(0) insted of cursor.getInt(0) do it effect on result

Comment: catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();    return arrData;
        }   you will get some error in blue color